VB.Net Receive Data From WiFi device
I have an older weather station that uses WiFi to transmit data to a console.  Unfortunately the console doesn't work any more and I'm trying to write a Windows app in VB.Net that can connect to and receive the data from the weather station.  I'm having trouble finding documentation on this. Could someone point me in the right direction?  Many Thanks

It actually depends on how your device sends data. If it is common (legacy) WiFi device and connects to AP then all you need to do is just use WinSock to connect to it by its IP address and then receive data as from any other IP device. If your device is WiFi Direct device than you need to use WFD functions to connect to device first Then, again, use WinSock to receive data.

Many thanks for this.  I'm familiar with WinSock but not WFD Functions, and can't find any references to it.  Please could you explain or point me towards some documentation?

Here is good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect?view=winrt-26100
